# Ruby - IMAP iterate multiple folders / select multiple folders

Tags: ruby, imap

This is my IMAP code:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('outlook.office365.com', 993, true)
imap.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
imap.examine("FOLDER1")
imap.search(["SINCE", "17-Dec-2020"]).each do |message_id|
  envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
  subject = Mail::Encodings.unquote_and_convert_to( envelope.subject, 'utf-8' )
  next unless subject.include?("SOME TXT")
  body = imap.fetch(message_id, "BODY[]")[0].attr["BODY[]"]
  mail = Mail.new(body)
  mail.attachments.each do |a|
    next unless File.extname(a.filename) == ".pdf"
    File.open("/path/to/file/pdfscript/#{a.filename}", 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(a.body.decoded)
    end
  end
end
```

Right now I have it setup only for "FOLDER1", but I have a lot of folders that I need to get files from. Is it possible to add multiple folders? Something like

```
imap.examine("FOLDER1", "FOLDER2", "FOLDER3", "FOLDER4")
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. You have to loop around everything after LOGIN, or else use several TCP connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by making an array

```
array_of_folders = ["Folder1","Folder2","Folder3","Folder4"]
```

and made an `.each`

```
array_of_folders.each do |folders|
imap.examine(folders) # takes each folder
# Rest of the code
end
```

Comment: Tip: For arrays of single words use `%w[ Folder1 Folder2 ... ]` which avoids a lot of syntax noise.

Comment: Ruby also tends to use the `array_of_folders` naming convention as well, unlike Python and others.